# What is the purpose of RecordComponent::getDeclaringRecord

Tags: java, java-record, java-16

`RecordComponent` has a method `getDeclaringRecord`. I can't seem to understand what is the purpose of it, especially since it's `public`.

The only way to get a `RecordComponent` is via calling `Record::getRecordComponents`, if I do call it like this, I already know the record that declares that `RecordComponent`? I can't seem to understand its actual purpose.

I also can't connect the dots of why the return type of that is not a `Class<? extends Record>`...

Comment: if you pass that component off to other things, those other things might not know what the originating record was ... so wouldn't it make sense for them to have the opportunity to call `getDeclaringRecord`?

Comment: 1. Mostly for the purposes of lookup to which Record does a component belongs to. Can see some usage within the same class in JDK for annotation processing. 2. +1, specifically with the Javadoc reference of `getRecordComponents`.

Comment: @Naman yeah, the first one was so obvious that I missed it. The second I guess is that `Class<? extends Record>` would not have any benefit. you are more then welcome to provide an answer, if you want

Comment: [`Member.getDeclaringClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#getDeclaringClass()), [`Enum.getDeclaringClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass()), [`Class.getDeclaringClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaringClass()), [`Annotation.annotationType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#annotationType()), `Parameter.getDeclaringExecutable()`, …

Comment: @Holger excellent, thank you. At 1AM when I posted that it was not that obvious, and now, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was a bit too obvious to be honest. When you pass a `RecordComponent` around, how are the receivers of such an argument supposed to know what record this belongs to? Well obviously by calling `getDeclaringRecord`.

It all makes sense of its internal usage in `RecordComponent` too, where it finds annotations based on the `Class` that is returned from calling this method.

The second point about `Class<? extends Record>` probably is that in practice this makes little sense. Even if `getDeclaringRecord` would return a `Class<? extends Record>`, if would not further narrow the methods that could be called on such a return type. So I guess, this is done because of that reason.